# Beautiful soup is not iterating properly through pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a function that **scrapes** book names from goodreads using python and Beautifulsoup.

I've realized some goodread pages have a common url that have the form:
"https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/" + **category_name** + "?page=" + **page_number** so I've made a function that receives a category name and a max page range in order to iterate from page 1 to max_pages.

The problem is that every time the program iterates it doesn't update the page but instead goes to the first (default) page for the category. I've tried to provide the full url like for example: *https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/art?page=2* but it still doesn't work so I'm guessing it might be that BeautifulSoup converts the url I'm passing into another format that's not working, but I don't know.

```py
def scrape_category(category_name, search_range):

    book_names = []

    for i in range(search_range):
        quote_page = "https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/" + category_name + "?page=" + str(i + 1)
        page = urlopen(quote_page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
        names = soup.find_all('a', attrs={"class":'bookTitle'})

        for name in names:
                book_name = name.text
                book_name = re.sub(r'\"','',book_name)
                book_names.append(book_name)

    return book_names
```

The result from this code is always the book names from the first page of the category I'm passing as parameter, never the *second*, *third* ... or *n* page from range 1 to max_pages that I'm requesting.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same books when I enter https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/art?page=2 and https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/art?page=15 in my browser. This is not a problem in BeautifulSoup, this is just how this site was built.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I actually can see different books when I enter! I'm using Google Chrome and aside of that it seems to me weird that a webpage like goodreads shows you same books in different pages.

Comment: I don't see different pages (i.e. on my machine there is no option to navigate between pages). Perhaps you are logged in? Anyhow, now you know that this option exists. Not getting the same page as you got in your browser is a common problem in web scraping. If you want to make sure you are getting the right pages try using selenium for fetching the page.

Comment: When I am not signed in I see the same page with both links. When I sign in I see different pages. Depending on how they are doing the login (I haven't looked close enough at it to know) you can probably login with beautifulsoup and get what you want.